# How can I echo out the user id in user meta?

Tags: wp-query

I need to generate a unique ID number for each new member. I was going to use WP_query, but am not getting anything but an array.

Comment: I am unsure what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to generate a user ID or are you trying to display the user ID? If  you are generating a new user ID why not just use the one WP assigns?

Comment: That's what I will probably do, I just don't know how to add it to a members information, ie. username, email, ID

Comment: I am still unsure of what you want to do, but it seems that you want to _add_ information to a user. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: I want to grab the user id, and have it print out with the rest of the user profile stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the info on the current user logged in you can use `get_currentuserinfo`. [[Codex]](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo)

*Example from Codex*

```
<?php global $current_user;
      get_currentuserinfo();

      echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
      echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . "\n";
      echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . "\n";
      echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . "\n";
      echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . "\n";
      echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . "\n";
?>
```

Or if you want display the info for a user that is not the current user logged in, you can use `get_userdata`. [[Codex]](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata)

The two links to the WP Codex should provide you with the syntax of the two functions. If you have any further questions or they did not work please ask.

Comment: Thanks! Hey, just a quick question, would you say this is the best way to create a unique number for a member? I was going to use rand(1,0000000) but it is random, and keeps changing. I came to the conclusion that the user ID is really the best way to make sure each users number is unique. Sound safe?

Comment: The User ID will always be unique because it auto increments in the database and the column is set to unique, so you should be fine.

Comment: How can I do this? I cannot seem to get it to echo out in each members profile area?

Comment: What is the code you are using?

Comment: ' <?php $user_number = get_userdata( $userid ); ?> <span>My User Number is: <?php echo $user_number; ?> <br /> '

Comment: If you want the information for the user logged in you should be using `get_currentuserinfo`. I have updated my post with some example code that I borrowed from the Codex.

Comment: The problem I am having with that, is it shows an ID, but it always show id of 1. I am going to have a lot of members on at the same time, and need them to be able to see each others ID's.

Comment: Do you want to see _all_ the members registered or only the ones online at the moment?

Comment: All, it's a community, so everyone should be able to look up members by their number, or at least see them when they want,

Comment: Got it echo '<p class="profile-fields"><strong>Inmate Number: </strong><span style="font-weight:bold; color:red;">'.bp_displayed_user_id().'</span></p>';